Orthogonal space of polynomials
Let $f \colon [0,+\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. Assume that for any non-negative integer $n$, the function $f(t) t^n$ in integrable in $(0,+\infty)$ and
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} f(t) t^n \mathrm{d} t = 0.
$$
Could we conclude $f \equiv 0$ on $[0,+\infty)$?
Note that we do not assume any growth rate or dacay rate of $f$. We just assumed the continuity of $f$.

This isn't true : a log-normal distribution of parameter $0$ and $1$ isn't determined by its moments (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probl%C3%A8me_des_moments).
For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, define $g_\alpha :x\mapsto f(x)(1+\alpha\sin(2\pi\ln(x))$ with $f:x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\ln(x)^2)$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}x^ng_\alpha(x),dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} x^nf(x),dx$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ but $g_\alpha \neq f$ if $\alpha\neq 0$

No, this is is a classical counterexample: $f:t\mapsto t^{-\ln(t)}\sin(2\pi\ln(t))$, it is continuous and has vanishing moments. Indeed, for any natural integer $n$, the change of variable $u=\ln(t)$ then $v=u-(n+1)/2$ relates the integral of $t\mapsto t^n f(t)$ on $\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ to the one of $v\mapsto e^{-v^2}\sin(2\pi v)$ on $\mathbf{R}$ which vanishes because the integrand is odd.
